# Google structural data atom error

Tags: html

I currently have a webpage that returns a weird error I have not seen before, you can see the error here:

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.voormeubels.nl

Error I am receiving is as following:

```
Atom XML Error (line 2): element "html" not allowed here; expected element "feed" (with xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
```

Anyone had this before? I can't see what is wrong with the HTML markup.

Comment: I am also receiving this error for some of the websites I manage. It was working perfectly fine yesterday when I checked it. I would assume it is a temporary bug. I even receive this error when I check Wordpress.com. https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.com%2F

Comment: Try posting in this thread on Google Groups to give attention to the bug: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/xUTsF2wRDtc;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/category$3Astructured-data%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that some problem with google data testing tool, we started to experience the same problem also we checked random sites - the same issue
for example https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tripadvisor.ca

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this same issue on my classic asp home page.  Originally, I was using:

```
<!doctype html>
```

and seeing the error:

```
Atom XML Error (line 1): The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Changing to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

yielded the new error:

```
Atom XML Error (line 2): element "html" not allowed here; expected element "feed" (with xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
```

I still don't have a fix though.

Pasting only the structured data into the Google Structured Data Testing Tool shows 0 errors.  I’ve even tried recreating the structured data using https://www.jamesdflynn.com/json-ld-schema-generator/

I would also recommend putting your site through the structured data linter at http://linter.structured-data.org/

Using the linter, I find the error:

```
htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' Element script embeds close tag
```